# Why are redirected user profiles read-only when accessed on the storage server?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, folder-redirection

I've set up folder redirection for my user profile in our domain. I noticed something weird when I logged on to the server on which the user profile data is located. All my redirected folders are read-only on this system.

For example, there's this INI file by Firefox:

```
\\windows.oliver.de\UserData\Profiles\OliverSalzburg\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini
```

`\\windows.oliver.de\UserData` would be a DFS namespace containing one entry, `Profiles` which is pointed to a shared volume on my server `storage.windows.oliver.de`.

When logging on to any system in the domain, I will be able to write to the .ini file just fine. When logging on to `storage.windows.oliver.de`, I won't be able to write to it. This is also indicated when I try to start FirefoxPortable:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand the *why* part of this question, but, at least, I found a solution.

I'm now reversing the folder redirection policies in a new GPO, which I apply on the computer level to the storage system. You're gonna want to make sure to [activate](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2548.windows-server-understand-user-group-policy-loopback-processing-mode.aspx) [loopback processing mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978513.aspx) on the new GPO as well to fully replace the users folder redirection settings.